# If the name id and the class have the same name how can get the text name of the class?

Tags: class

1. If i have this html id

   ```
    <div id="skay_1">Car</div>
   ```
2. And this html class

   ```
    <div class="skay_1">Text</div>
   ```

   How can get the name Text of class and returned on the page for example:

   ## My name is " Text "

Comment: Why Vote down? this is not a question?

Answer (score -1):

```
$('div #skay_1').val();
document.getElementById('id-name here').value();
```

Comment: and this is return the value on the site when the site is load?

Comment: Not work or i dont use it corect can you show an example code?